# Outlier Flagging not working: issue with logic or issue with code?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to detect outliers in timeseries in pandas in simple way. In the code shared below, I am adding noise from '2024-04-01' to '2024-05-30'. But, my code is not detecting it: any flaw in the code or logic?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

baseline_price = 100.00
dates = pd.date_range(start='2024-01-01', end='2024-12-31', freq='D')
baseline_prices = pd.Series(baseline_price, index=dates)
baseline_prices += np.random.uniform(10, 15, size=len(baseline_prices))

shifted_prices = baseline_prices.copy()
shifted_prices.loc['2024-04-01':'2024-05-30'] += np.random.uniform(1000, 1015, size=60)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates, 'Stock Price': shifted_prices})

window_size, multiplier = 30, 2
rolling_mean = df['Stock Price'].rolling(window=window_size, center=True).mean()
rolling_std = df['Stock Price'].rolling(window=window_size, center=True).std()

upper_bound = rolling_mean + (multiplier * rolling_std)
lower_bound = rolling_mean - (multiplier * rolling_std)
outliers = df[(df['Stock Price'] > upper_bound) | (df['Stock Price'] < lower_bound)]

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Stock Price'], label='Stock Price')
plt.plot(df['Date'], rolling_mean, label=f'{window_size}-day Rolling Mean')
plt.fill_between(df['Date'], upper_bound, lower_bound, color='gray', alpha=0.2, label=f'{multiplier}-sigma Bounds')
plt.scatter(outliers['Date'], outliers['Stock Price'], color='red', label='Outliers')
plt.title('Stock Price with Outliers')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot detect outliers is that the noise you introduce is really (and I mean REALLY) huge compared to your baseline noise (baseline noise = 10-15, and addictional noise 1000-1015?!?). Here I reduced it significantly to 12-15.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

baseline_price = 100.00
dates = pd.date_range(start='2024-01-01', end='2024-12-31', freq='D')
baseline_prices = pd.Series(baseline_price, index=dates)
baseline_prices += np.random.uniform(10, 15, size=len(baseline_prices))

shifted_prices = baseline_prices.copy()
shifted_prices.loc['2024-04-01':'2024-05-30'] += np.random.uniform(12, 15, size=60)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates, 'Stock Price': shifted_prices})

window_size, multiplier = 30, 2
rolling_mean = df['Stock Price'].rolling(window=window_size, center=True).mean()
rolling_std = df['Stock Price'].rolling(window=window_size, center=True).std()

upper_bound = rolling_mean + (multiplier * rolling_std)
lower_bound = rolling_mean - (multiplier * rolling_std)
outliers = df[(df['Stock Price'] > upper_bound) | (df['Stock Price'] < lower_bound)]

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Stock Price'], label='Stock Price')
plt.plot(df['Date'], rolling_mean, label=f'{window_size}-day Rolling Mean')
plt.fill_between(df['Date'], upper_bound, lower_bound, color='gray', alpha=0.2, label=f'{multiplier}-sigma Bounds')
plt.scatter(outliers['Date'], outliers['Stock Price'], color='red', label='Outliers')
plt.title('Stock Price with Outliers')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]

Another issue you need to addresss is the indexing. Here is my suggestion

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

baseline_price = 100.00
dates = pd.date_range(start='2024-01-01', end='2024-12-31', freq='D')
baseline_prices = pd.Series(baseline_price, index=dates)
baseline_prices += np.random.uniform(10, 15, size=len(baseline_prices))

shifted_prices = baseline_prices.copy()
shifted_prices.loc['2024-04-01':'2024-05-30'] += np.random.uniform(12, 15, size=60)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Stock Price': shifted_prices})
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)

window_size, multiplier = 30, 2
rolling_mean = df['Stock Price'].rolling(window=window_size, center=True).mean()
rolling_std = df['Stock Price'].rolling(window=window_size, center=True).std()

upper_bound = rolling_mean + (multiplier * rolling_std)
lower_bound = rolling_mean - (multiplier * rolling_std)

outliers = df[(df['Stock Price'] > upper_bound) | (df['Stock Price'] < lower_bound)]

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(df.index, df['Stock Price'], label='Stock Price')
plt.plot(df.index, rolling_mean, label=f'{window_size}-day Rolling Mean', color='orange')
plt.fill_between(df.index, upper_bound, lower_bound, color='gray', alpha=0.2, label=f'{multiplier}-sigma Bounds')
plt.scatter(outliers.index, outliers['Stock Price'], color='red', label='Outliers', marker='o')
plt.title('Stock Price with Outliers')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

which produces
[image]